# Quartz 2 + spring 4 - clusterisation breaks when spring is configured to overwrite existing jobs

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm seeing a strange behaviour in Quartz, when it's configured in clustered mode, and spring is configured to `overwriteExistingJobs=true`.

My question is: Is something wrong in my configuration? Can overwriteExistingJobs be used in clustered mode? Or is this a bug in Quartz? (as quartz should provide the invariant that a clustered job runs in only one node)

I have a SimpleTrigger that fires every second, which triggers a job that annotated with `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` and prints how many times the trigger has fired. The problem shows when I run run a second instance of the application; in this scenario, the job is fired on both instances with a different trigger count (and I can see in the database that there are updates with different values going to `qrtz_simple_triggers.times_triggered` .

When I set the property `overwriteExistingJobs=false`, quartz runs as expected, and the job is only run in one instance of the cluster.

I'm using

- MySQL 5.5 (innodb) as to store the jobs
- Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE
- Quartz 2.2.1

Here's my spring configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz" />
      <property name="username" value="quartz" />
      <property name="password" value="quartz" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>

   <bean name="myJobDetails" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
      <property name="jobClass" value="og.test.MyJob"/>
      <property name="durability" value="true"/>
      <property name="name" value="myJobDetails"/>
      <property name="group" value="myJobDetails"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="myJobDetailsSimpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
      <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJobDetails"/>
      <property name="startDelay" value="2000"/>
      <property name="repeatInterval" value="1000"/>
      <property name="name" value="myJobDetailsSimpleTrigger"/>
      <property name="group" value="myJobDetails"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="scheduler" class="og.test.TriggerCleaningSchedulerFactoryBean">
      <property name="quartzProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">MY_JOB_SCHEDULER</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">10</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
      <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
      <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>     <!-- offending property -->
      <property name="schedulerName" value="quartzScheduler"/>
      <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
      <property name="triggers">
         <list><ref bean="myJobDetailsSimpleTrigger"/></list>
      </property>

      <property name="jobDetails">
         <list><ref bean="myJobDetails" /></list>
      </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

And my job class

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class MyJob extends QuartzJobBean {
   @Override
   protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
      String jobName = ctx.getJobDetail().getKey().getName();
      String triggerName = ctx.getTrigger().getKey().getName();
      SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = (SimpleTrigger) ctx.getTrigger();
      int timesTriggered = simpleTrigger.getTimesTriggered();

      System.out.printf("%d - %s/%s - %d\n", System.currentTimeMillis(), jobName, triggerName, timesTriggered);
   }
}
```